# Failed to start glassfish server because Couldn't get lock for /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log

Tags: java, glassfish-3

```
admin@BRMSDEV:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/bin$ ./asadmin start-domain domain1
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:389)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:287)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:85)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:148)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:239)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.runCommandNotEmbedded(StartDomainCommand.java:122)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:257)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.executeCommand(AsadminMain.java:229)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:167)
Waiting for DAS to start .Error starting domain: domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 0.
```

Before it died, it produced the following output:

```
   Warning:  Cannot open log file: /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/jvm.log
admin@BRMSDEV:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/bin$ ./asadmin start-domain domain1
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:389)
at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:287)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:85)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:148)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:239)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.runCommandNotEmbedded(StartDomainCommand.java:122)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:257)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.executeCommand(AsadminMain.java:229)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:167)
Waiting for DAS to start .Error starting domain: domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 0.
```

Before it died, it produced the following output:

```
Warning:  Cannot open log file: /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/jvm.log
Warning:  Forcing option -XX:LogFile=/tmp/hs_pid2234.log
Jun 27, 2014 8:36:05 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain main
INFO: Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Jun 27, 2014 8:36:05 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain main
SEVERE: the domain directory is not writable.
java.lang.RuntimeException: the domain directory is not writable.
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMainHelper.verifyAndSetDomainRoot(ASMainHelper.java:233)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.AbstractMain.run(AbstractMain.java:89)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMainOSGi.run(ASMainOSGi.java:71)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.AbstractMain.start(AbstractMain.java:78)
at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:82)
Command start-domain failed.
```

I just installed glassfish in my host machine and changed the domain.xml with my host ip and started the server through the following command

*./asadmin start-domain domain1*

I got the above exceptions ,I am new to glassfish please help me out how to over come this issue ,
Thanks in advance 
@dinesh

Comment: This is not a question. It's a stack trace.

Comment: am getting this on windows

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and changing the directory permissions solved that issue. Try this:

1. `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/`
2. If you are using an ide like IntelliJ for example, you have to start the GlassFish Server inside the ide.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't have writing permissions to the folder /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/ and / or file server.log
... and / or the folder / file doesn't exist.

Try `sudo` or change the folder's permission settings.

Comment: sorry i changed the permissions but still I am getting the same problem .

Comment: Actually I installed glassfish in my ubuntu server ,then after I just edited domain.xml listener 4848 I added address as my server address ,them I am just save it and rebooted my server ,and started server with the following cmd..  "./asadmin start-domain domain1" I try as u said I change the permissions by using the following cmd chmod -R 755 <directoryName>,then i rebooted and try to start server again but no change ,getting same exceptions

Comment: This exact thing was happening to me. I had to use `sudo asadmin` instead of just asadmin